# Are there a thing call "semi-monad" or "counter-monad"?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

Well, I am studying Haskell Monads. When I read the Wikibook [Category theory](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory) article, I found that the signature of monad morphisms looks pretty like tautologies in logic, but you need to convert `M a` to `~~A`, here `~` is the logic negation.

```
return :: a -> M a -- Map to tautology A => ~~A, double negation introduction
(>>=) :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b -- Map to tautology ~~A => (A => ~~B) => ~~B
```

the other operations is also tautologies:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> M a -> M b -- Map to (A => B) -> (~~A => ~~B)
join :: M (M a) -> M a -- Map to ~~(~~A) => ~~A
```

It's also understood that according to the fact that the [Curry-Howard](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/The_Curry-Howard_isomorphism) correspondence of normal functional languages is the intuitive logic, not classical logic, so we cannot expect a tautology like `~~A => A` can have a correspondence.

But I am thinking of something else. Why the Monad can only relate to a double negation? what is the correspondence of single negation? This lead me to the following class definition:

```
class Nomad n where
    rfmap :: (a -> b) -> n b -> n a
    dneg :: a -> n (n a)

return :: Nomad n => a -> n (n a)
return = dneg
(>>=) :: Nomad n => n (n a) -> (a -> n (n b)) -> n (n b)
x >>= f = rfmap dneg $ rfmap (rfmap f) x
```

Here I defined a concept called "Nomad", and it supports two operations (both related to a logic axiom in intuitive logic). Notice the name "rfmap" means the fact that its signature is similar to functor's `fmap`, but the order of `a` and `b` are reversed in result. Now I can re-define the Monad operations with them, with replace `M a` to `n (n a)`.

So now let's go to the question part. The fact that Monad is a concept from category theory seems to mean that my "Nomad" is also a category theory concept. So what is it? Is it useful? Are there any papers or research results exists in this topic?

Comment: `rfmap` is an operation on [contravariant functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/contravariant/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html).

Comment: The title of your question asked whether there is a "semi-monad", but your actual question went in a different direction. In the interest of completeness it should probably be noted that a "semi-monad" might refer to a monad that does not have a unit operation (i.e., in Haskell, does not have a well-defined 'return :: a -> m a'), or whose unit operation does not behave as a unit, e.g., '(return x) >>= f =/= f x'. This parallels the notion of a 'semi-group' being a monoid without a unit (or well-behaved unit).

Comment: When I say "semi-monad" I mean the fact that `Nomad` looks like half of a `Monad`, since `n (n a)` is a well defined `Monad`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Double negation is a *particular* monad

```
data Void --no constructor because it is uninhabited

newtype DN a = DN {runDN :: (a -> Void) -> Void}

instance Monad DN where
   return x = DN $ \f -> f x
   m >>= k  = DN $ \c -> runDN m (\a -> runDN (k a) c))
```

actually, this is an example of a more general monad

```
type DN = Cont Void
newtype Cont r a = Cont {runCont :: (a -> r) -> r}
```

which is the monad for continuation passing.

A concept like "monad" is not defined just by a signature, but also by some laws.  So, here is a question, what should the laws for your construction be?

```
(a -> b) -> f b -> f a
```

is the signature of a method well known to category theory, the **contravariant functor**.  It obeys essentially the same laws as functors (preserves (co)composition and identity).  Actually, a contravariant functor is exactly a functor to the oppositite category.  Since we are interested in "haskell functors" which are supposed to be endo-functors, we can see that a "haskell contravariant functor" is a functor `Hask -> Hask_Op`.

On the other hand, what about

```
a -> f (f a)
```

what laws should this have?  I have a suggestion.  In category theory, it is possible to map between Functors.  Given two functors from `F, G` each from category `C` to category `D`, a *natural transformation* from `F` to `G` is a morphism in `D`

```
forall a. F a -> G a
```

that obeys certain coherence laws.  You can do a lot with natural transformations, including using them to define a "functor category."  But, the classic joke (due to Mac Lane) is that categories were invented to talk about functors, functors were invented to talk about natural transformations, and natural transformations were invented to talk about *adjunctions*.

A functor `F : D -> C` and a functor `G : C -> D` form an adjunction from `C` to `D` if there exist two natural transformations

```
unit : Id -> G . F
counit : F . G -> Id
```

This idea of an adjunction is a frequent way of understanding monads.  Every adjunction gives rise to a monad in a totally natural way.  That is, since the composition of these two functors is an endofunctor, and you have something akin to return (the unit), all you need is the join.  But that is easy, join is just a function `G . F . G . F -> G . F` which you get by just using the counit "in the middle".

So, then with all this, what is it that you are looking for?  Well

```
dneg :: a -> n (n a)
```

looks exactly like the `unit` of the adjunction of a contravariant functor with itself.  Therefore, your `Nomad` type is likely (certainly if your use of it to construct a monad is correct) exactly the same as "a contravariant functor which is self adjoint."  Searching for self adjoint functors will lead you back to Double-negation and Continuation passing...which is just where we started!

---

EDIT: Almost certainly some of the arrows above are backwards.  The basic idea is right, though.  You can work it out yourself using the citations below:

The best books on category theory are probably,

- Steve Awodey, *Category Theory*
- Sanders Mac Lane, *Categories for the Working Mathematician*

although numerous more approachable intro books exist including Benjamin Pierces book on Category Theory for computer scientists.

Video lectures online

- The Category Theory lectures by Steve Awodey from the [Oregon Programming Language Summer School](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Activities/summerschool/summer12/curriculum.html)
- The Catsters short lectures on youtube, [indexed here](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Edsko.de.Vries/ct/catsters/linear.php), pay particular attention to the videos on adjunctions

A number of papers explore the adjunction angle on the continuation monad, for example

- Hayo Thielecke, *Continuation Semantics and Self-adjointness*

The search terms "self adjoint", "continuation", and "monad" are good.  Also, a number of bloggers have written about these issues.  If you google "where do monads come from" you get useful results like [this one](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/09/where_do_monads_come_from.html) from the n category cafe, or [this one](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/12/where-do-monads-come-from.html) from sigfpe.  Also Sjoerd Vissche's [link](http://comonad.com/reader/2011/monads-from-comonads/) to the Comonad reader.

Comment: `dneg` is also the counit (the arrow flips because the components of the counit are arrows in Hask^op). And the natural isomorphism required for an adjunction homC(F–,–) → homD(–,G–) is the identity because hom_(Hask^op)(a,b) = hom_Hask(b,a). So a `Nomad` is exactly "a contravariant functor which is self adjoint."

Comment: Great answer. Can you please add some reference or suggest some further reading sources in the text? I would like to mark it as answer.

Comment: Sorry to open an old thread, but when you said "covariant" did you mean "contravariant"?

Comment: @JonathanSterling probably.  I think I have now fixed it.  I had no memory of writing this, so it was fun to see again.

Answer (score 8):

That would be a self-adjoint contravariant functor. `rfmap` provides the contravariant functor part, and `dneg` is the unit and counit of the adjunction.

`Op r` is an example, which creates the continuation monad. See the contravariant modules in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/adjunctions for some code.

You should read http://comonad.com/reader/2011/monads-from-comonads/, which is related and very interesting.